# infopath hide fields based on sp group

Tags: infopath

Is it possible to hide fields in InfoPath form based on sp group. Can you a proven link or some cool ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at [InfoPath: Restrict visibility to users in a SharePoint Group](http://info.akgroup.com/blog-0/bid/69277/InfoPath-Restrict-visibility-to-users-in-a-SharePoint-Group)

Answer (score 0):

There is a codeplex tool to control the display setting on a field.

https://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/

This is for sp 2007. May be there is a sp2010 version out there.